# VBS opens a CMD but can't read next commands to go on other directory

Tags: postgresql, vbscript, cmd

I am trying to create vbs file so that it will be executed by the MS Scheduler in order to backup my Postgresql database because i can't seem to find a way in using agent since i installed it but it is not appearing in the UI of PGAdmin III that was installed when i used Odoo. I am using windows 10.

Here is my .vbs file

```
Set ShellCmd = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

ShellCmd.run "cmd cd\ cd 'Program Files' cd Odoo 9.0-20161004 cd PostgreSQL cd bin pg_dump -h localhost -p 5432 -U openpg -f 'C:/BackupFiles/Sample.backup' -d 120120161800"

WScript.Echo "Success!"
```

When i run this, the command line isn't going anywhere. Even just "cmd cd\" the cmd does nothing. I'ts a quite simple problem but i can't get my automated backup working if i can't run a simple vbs command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a vbs script, you should just use a .bat or .cmd batch file:

```
c:
cd "\Program Files\Odoo 9.0-20161004\PostgreSQL\bin"
pg_dump -h localhost -p 5432 -U openpg -f 'C:/BackupFiles/Sample.backup' -d 120120161800"
```

Generally, we do not use `ShellCmd.run "cmd ...."` in vbs to execute multiple commands in one statement.

Comment: With vbs, the vbs can run automatically as administrator (i guess) because with at .bat it's giving me a Permission Denied output. Is there anyway that this thing will run in a background process where the cmd window won't be seen executing the command while it is loading? Thanks for the reply! A good idea!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have a workaround now but i am using batch file just as you suggested. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Your ShellCmd is heavily broken. I suggest instead of using .Run take the .Exec method to catch the output - at least until problems are solved. I don't know if your pg_dump requires to be run inside that same folder, if not this might work:

```
Dim WshShell, oExec, s
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Program = """C:\Program Files\Odoo 9.0-20161004\PostgreSQL\bin\pg_dump"""
Options = " -h localhost -p 5432 -U openpg -f 'C:/BackupFiles/Sample.backup' -d 120120161800"

Set oExec = WshShell.Exec(Program & Options)

Do While Not oExec.StdOut.AtEndOfStream
    s = s & oExec.StdOut.ReadLine() & vbCrLf
Loop

WScript.Echo "oExec.Status=" & oExec.Status
Wscript.Echo s
```

Comment: I tried running it and gave me an error and it says "Parameter is incorrect at line 7" Which is at .Exec. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: Had a typo with using `Programm` and `Program` - Edited above.

Comment: Not working. Wasn't able to backup the database. But thanks for the answer! Though i have a working solution now. Had a workaround using a batch file and then MS Task Scheduler. Thanks for reaching out!